# Como conectarme a as400 desde csharp

Tags: db2, as400

Buenas tardes necesito ayuda 
como puedo conectarme a as400 base de datos db2 ddesde c sharp llamando los datos a un datatable y mostrandolos en un datagridview ?
debido a que consigo pura informacion de conexion pero desde una aplicacion de consola
agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Hola @Muni, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega la dependencia **IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries** (con NuGet) a tu proyecto, luego podrás usar objetos como iDB2Connection, iDB2Command, iDB2DataReader entre otros para realizar las consultas. Dado AS400 difiere un poco de las otras bases de dato el Connection String a usar debe ser algo así:

```
Data Source=IP_o_NOMBRESISTEMA;User ID=NOMBRE_USUARIO;Password=EL_PASSWORD;Default Collection=QGPL;LibraryList=LIBRERIA1,LIBRERIA2
```

Notese que hay una libreria inicial o principal asociada a la llave **Default Collection**, en este caso con el valor **QGPL** que es el valor por defecto, sugiero que en el caso de necesitar acceder mas librerias (esquemas de la bd) las relaciones separadas por coma (,) al parametro **LibraryList**

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una situación algo contrastante con la del estimado;
Mi situación es que después de haber cerrado mi conexión(desde VB), en el servidor AS400 la sesión queda con un estatus TIMW (Espera a que finalice un tiempo para cerrar la hebra inicial) yo quiero cerrar esa hebra, me han dicho que use "SIGNOFF" desde mi aplicación. la hago de esta manera pero no me funciona.

Public Sub myfunction()
Dim finhilo As String = "SIGNOFF)"
ExecuteNonQuery(finhilo) ''Esta es una función que ejecuta un comando IDB2COMMAND
End Sub

Podría alguien indicarme de que manera lo puedo hacer

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [ES.so], por favor no uses el area de respuestas para hacer preguntas, mejor postea tu propia pregunta o si tienes el nivel suficiente inicia una recompensa por alguna pregunta sin respuesta, no esta de mas que leas [ask]

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/310836)